# read_csv does not work separate commas and not capture separate rows

Tags: r

I am trying to parse a text log file like this, I can use the default read.csv to parse this file.

> test <- read.csv("test.txt", header=FALSE)

It separated all comma parts, though not perfectly put in a dataframe, further manipulation can be done to improve.
However, I can not seem to do so using readr package

> test <- read_csv("test.txt", header=FALSE)

All observations turn into 1 row, no separation between commas.
I am learning this package so any help would be great.

> {"dev_id":"f8:f0:05:xx:db:xx","data":[{"dist":[7270,7269,7269,7275,7270,7271,7265,7270,7274,7267,7271,7271,7266,7263,7268,7271,7266,7265,7270,7268,7264,7270,7261,7260]},{"temp":0},{"hum":0},{"vin":448}],"time":4485318,"transmit_time":4495658,"version":"1.0"}
>   {"dev_id":"f8:xx:05:xx:d9:xx","data":[{"dist":[6869,6868,6867,6871,6866,6867,6863,6865,6868,6869,6868,6860,6865,6866,6870,6861,6865,6868,6866,6864,6866,6866,6865,6872]},{"temp":0},{"hum":0},{"vin":449}],"time":4405316,"transmit_time":4413715,"version":"1.0"}
>   {"dev_id":"xx:f0:05:e8:da:xx","data":[{"dist":[5775,5775,5777,5772,5777,5770,5779,5773,5776,5777,5772,5768,5782,5772,5765,5770,5770,5767,5767,5777,5766,5763,5773,5776]},{"temp":0},{"hum":0},{"vin":447}],"time":4461316,"transmit_time":4473307,"version":"1.0"}
>   {"dev_id":"xx:f0:xx:e8:xx:0a","data":[{"dist":[4358,4361,4355,4358,4359,4359,4361,4358,4359,4360,4360,4361,4361,4359,4359,4356,4357,4361,4359,4360,4358,4358,4362,4359]},{"temp":0},{"hum":0},{"vin":424}],"time":5190320,"transmit_time":5198748,"version":"1.0"}

Comment: Your sample data looks to be in JSON format.  Trying using the` jsonlite` or similar package to parse the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. I found it using ndjson::stream_in

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dave2e pointing out that this file is in JSON format, I found the way to parse it using ndjson::stream_in.